# How do I keep the "&" in a string when I parse JSON in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, encoding

I can't find an easy answer to this, and so I am turning to Stack Overflow.

I have a JSON file named "flavor.json" like this:

```
{"flavor" : "Cookies & Cream"}
```

In ruby, I want to create a new JSON file named "ice_cream_flavor.json" like this:

```
{"ice cream flavor" : "Cookies & Cream"}
```

Here's my code...

```
json = JSON.parse(File.read("flavor.json"))
new_json = {"ice cream flavor" => json["flavor"]}
File.write("ice_cream_flavor.json", new_json.to_json)
```

However, the newly created ice_cream_flavor.json file looks like this:

```
{"ice cream flavor" : "Cookies \u0026 Cream"}
```

Problem:
I don't want the \u0026. I want the &. How do I do this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. Which Ruby are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you tell us the version (`JSON::VERSION`)?

Comment: It works as you want (with &). Windows 7, ruby 1.9.3 and ruby 2.1.6

Comment: At which point does `&` become `\u0026`? `read`, `parse`, `to_json`, or `write`?

Comment: That's weird... I'm not sure why you guys can't reproduce it.
Rails version: 3.2.19
Ruby version: 2.1.4
json gem: 1.8.3

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you did wrong but i tried it and it worked just fine, alright let say that your file `flavor.json` is located at the path: `C:\flavor.json`.

here's what i did(just your code), i added the require methode to load Json class.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
json = JSON.parse(File.read("C:\\flavor.json"))
new_json = {"ice cream flavor" => json["flavor"]}
File.write("C:\\ice_cream_flavor.json", new_json.to_json)
```

The result are just like what you want:

```
 if you check the file  `flavor.json` its content => {"flavor" : "Cookies & Cream"}
 if you check the file  `ice_cream_flavor.json` its content => {"ice cream flavor":"Cookies & Cream"}
```